# POST http://localhost:3000/auth/signin 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have am trying to connect my frontend to my backend using axios to make API calls. My client is running on port 3000 and server on port 8800. When I try to fetch videos it is working fine, means the proxy server is setup correctly.

The code are as follows

This is the signin.jsx handleLogin function triggered on clicking the signin button

```
const handleLogin = async (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    try{
      const res = await axios.post("/auth/signin", {username, password});
      console.log(res.data);
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

- Here I've tried to set a proxy server in my client package.json.

```
{
  "name": "video_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "timeago.js": "^4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8800/api"
}
```

And I've been trying it at insomnia without error. How do I solve this and get port 3000 connected 8800 and signin working ?[image: insomnia]

Comment: The URL in insomnia and in your code is not the same: , looks like you are missing api in your axios.post path (should be `axios.post("/api/auth/signin", ...)`

Comment: @TBA looks right to me - axios posts to http://localhost:3000/auth/signin which gets proxied to http://localhost:8800/api/auth/signin . Did I get that right?

Comment: @Codebling correct - I've missed the proxy setting the package.json